Using secrets for bdd test cases
I've written bdd test cases for my application and for that, I want to use secrets.json values for ClientId and ClientSecrets.
I'm using msal approach to generate clientid and clientsecrets.I've also used Get.EnvironmentVariable("") and also used Configuration.MsalClientSecret() but nothing seems to be fetching the secrets.json values.....
Below is the authentication code using msal approach.
namespace bddTests.Driver
{
    class MsalAuthentication : IAuthentication
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MsalAuthentication(ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.xUnitOutput = xUnitOutput;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_configuration["Msal:ClientId"])
                .WithClientSecret(Configuration.MsalClientSecret())
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(Configuration.MsalTenantId()))
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { Configuration.MsalScope()};

            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result.AccessToken;

        }
    }
}

This is where I'm calling this method in another file:
namespace bddTests.Driver
{
    public class Project : IProject
    {
        private string idToken;
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public LogCompanion(ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput,IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.xUnitOutput = xUnitOutput;
            _configuration = configuration;
            Initialize().Wait();
        }
        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            await RequestToken().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        public HttpResponseMessage GetEventPageAsync(FilterMetadata payload)
        {
            return Configuration.LogHttpClient
                .ForService(Configuration.EndpointConfiguration)
                .PostWithPolling($"api/apiname", idToken, xUnitOutput, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")); ;
        }

 public async Task RequestToken()
 {
     idToken = null;
     idToken = await new MsalAuthentication(xUnitOutput, _configuration).GetAccessToken().ConfigureAwait(false);
     xUnitOutput.WriteLine("Msal Id Token:" + idToken);


 }

And this is the step definition file:
namespace bddTests.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding, Scope(Feature = "Predefined CRUD Status")]
    public class PredefineFilterSteps
    {
        private readonly IPredefinedFilterDrive predefinedApiDriver;
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput;
        public PredefineFilterSteps(ITestOutputHelper xUnitOutput, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.xUnitOutput = xUnitOutput;
            predefinedApiDriver = new PredefinedWebDriver(xUnitOutput, configuration);

        }

And I'm getting this error when implementing this Iconfiguration apprach:
**Message: 
BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration (resolution path: LogCompanion_bddTests.StepDefinitions.FileUploadSteps)
**
My secrets.json file is:
 "Msal": {
   "MsalClientId": "12345",
   "MsalClientSecret": "abc-123"
 }

I'm using msal approach to generate clientid and clientsecrets.I've also used Get.EnvironmentVariable("") and also used Configuration.MsalClientSecret() but nothing seems to be fetching the secrets.json values.....
Is it possible to implement bdd test cases using secrets.json?
If yes, How I can implement bdd test cases with IConfiguration approach? (Not finding anything for the same on internet)
